# How To Remove Outliers Properly From Simple Dataset

Tags: dataset, outliers

Say I have a simple data set that describes height of males in a classroom.

I decide that whatever value falls 3.29 standard deviations away from the mean is actually an outlier. When removing these identified outlier values and reanalyzing my data set, should I recalculate the max 3.29 standard deviation mark based on the new dataset and keep removing outliers again and again until I have a data set where nothing falls over nor under 3.29 stdev away from the mean? Or is what I just said just silly?

Comment: An outlier would be someone who you don't believe is really part of the dataset you wish to analyze. Do you think that 3.29 sd from the mean makes them no longer male? You need another justification to remove a data point.

Comment: Many statistically-minded people would never remove outliers just because they are far out in the tails. The example of human height is one of many where you have ways of finding out whether values are credible and using judgment rather than some numerical rule. I'd read around widely on outlier threads here. There are many procedures easier to defend than the one you are contemplating.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outliers?sort=votes&pageSize=30

Comment: OK I must state that the example I gave was a simple one just to make a point but I am actually trying to model the expected performance of machine after 1 year. But if you had a dataset for any type of analysis whether its machine performance, male height, player performance ..What is the proper way of getting rid of outlier values? Give me a way

Comment: Please explain why you think you need to "get rid" of such values. If you trust your data, then they reflect what really happened with the machine.  Removing them could unrealistically alter your conclusions.

Comment: Say we had an electricity outage and the machine stop working for multiple months by the time someone noticed. This would affect the output results of the machine. Since I cant got back and check for that amount of detail with every single machine I am relying on picking out outlier data and not including them in my calculations

Comment: "Machine stopped working" sounds like a case of missing values, not outliers, to me. Yes, I know it's just another example, but you will have an uphill struggle here with these ideas. There is a broad consensus of active members against them.

Comment: You should use an estimator of location and scatter that is not sensitive to the removal of a handful of data points. The median and mad are good candidates: contrary to the mean and SD they will not be unduly swayed by a handful of far out observations.